# Why using WIC in my 32 bit application fails in Windows 7 32 bit?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, windows-7, wic

I have Win32 C++ sample application that uses [Windows Image Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Visual Studio Pro 2012 Update 2. I built this app for X86 and tested in Windows 7 X64 SP1 and Windows 7 X86 SP1. It works fine with the first one and it fails on the later with "class not registered".

If I build the same code with VS2008 it works fine.

The WIC instance is created in the sample app as follows:

```
#include "wincodec.h"
...
case WM_CREATE:
{
IWICImagingFactory *m_pIWICFactory;  
HRESULT hr = S_OK;

CoInitialize(NULL);
// create WIC factory (m_pIWICFactory)
hr = CoCreateInstance(
    &CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    &IID_IWICImagingFactory, 
    &m_pIWICFactory);
if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
    MessageBox(NULL, 
        L"CoCreateInstance(..IID_IWICImagingFactory..) failed!", 
        L"", MB_OK);
else
    MessageBox(NULL, 
        L"CoCreateInstance(..IID_IWICImagingFactory..) succeeded!", 
        L"", MB_OK);

CoUninitialize();
}
break;
...
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [breaking change in VS2012](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowswic/thread/e542d34a-a04b-455e-bd5b-957f162bab94) because it targets Windows 8 by default.

The solution is to specify `CLSID_WICImagingFactory1` instaed of `CLSID_WICImagingFactory` because the latter resolves to `CLSID_WICImagingFactory2`, which does not exist in Windows 7.

So try this

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_WICImagingFactory1, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
         &IID_IWICImagingFactory, &m_pIWICFactory);
```