# ID2D1HwndRenderTarget::CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap()

Tags: c++, winapi, direct2d

I am trying to use WIC to load picture from the file and display it on screen with Direct2D. I follow the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756686(v=vs.85).aspx) but I encounter a problem with the function CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap().

No matter which combination of [pixel formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756766(v=vs.85).aspx#supported_wic_formats) I use during `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget` creation and `IWICFormatConverter::Initialize()` function calling, function `CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap()` returns 0x88982f80  error (`WINCODEC_ERR_UNSUPPORTEDPIXELFORMAT`).

I call the function using the same `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget` which I use for drawing. Should I create another render target?

In the comment section in this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/416004c5-6b73-45cd-a820-92b6608e9bfd/id2d1rendertargetcreatebitmap-returns-0x88982f80?forum=windowssdk), someone wrote that `CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap()` should be called by DXGI surface render target. Does it mean that this function simply cannot be used with `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget`?

EDIT:

```
void LoadBitmapFromFile(ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* target, ID2D1Bitmap** ppBitmap)
{
    IWICImagingFactory* factory;
    IWICBitmapDecoder* decoder;
    IWICBitmapFrameDecode* frame;
    IWICFormatConverter* converter;

    CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory1,
                     NULL,
                     CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                     IID_IWICImagingFactory,
                     reinterpret_cast<void**>(&factory));

    factory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(L".png",
                                       NULL,
                                       GENERIC_READ,
                                       WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad,
                                       &decoder);

    decoder->GetFrame(0, &frame);

    factory->CreateFormatConverter(&converter);

    converter->Initialize(frame,
                          GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
                          WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,
                          NULL,
                          0.f,
                          WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut);

    target->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(frame, 0, ppBitmap);
}
```

ID2D1HwndRenderTarget is created like that:

```
ID2D1Factory* factory;
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* target;

D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &factory);

factory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
    D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_HARDWARE,
                                 D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED)), 
    D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hwnd, D2D1::SizeU(width, height)),
    &target);
```

Comment: Please show some code in [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap` expects `converter` as first parameter, not `frame`.

Use `CLSID_WICImagingFactory` instead of `CLSID_WICImagingFactory1`. The compiler will pick the right value. In my case it picks `CLSID_WICImagingFactory2`

The variable name for `IWICImagingFactory* factory` is hiding a global variable with the same name. This was probably not causing an error, but it's better to change it...

The handles need to be released.

```
HRESULT LoadBitmapFromFile(const wchar_t *filename, ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* target, ID2D1Bitmap** pBitmap)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_FALSE;
    IWICImagingFactory* wic_factory = NULL;
    IWICBitmapDecoder* decoder = NULL;
    IWICBitmapFrameDecode* frame = NULL;
    IWICFormatConverter* converter = NULL;

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWICImagingFactory, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&wic_factory));
    if FAILED(hr) goto clenaup;

    hr = wic_factory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(filename, NULL, GENERIC_READ, WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad, &decoder);
    if FAILED(hr) goto clenaup;

    hr = decoder->GetFrame(0, &frame);
    if FAILED(hr) goto clenaup;

    hr = wic_factory->CreateFormatConverter(&converter);
    if FAILED(hr) goto clenaup;

    hr = converter->Initialize(frame, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA, WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, NULL, 0.f, WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut);
    if FAILED(hr) goto clenaup;

    hr = target->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(converter, 0, pBitmap);
    if FAILED(hr) goto clenaup;

clenaup:
    safe_release(decoder);
    safe_release(converter);
    safe_release(frame);
    safe_release(wic_factory);
    return hr;
}
```

`CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)` can be called once in initialization.

```
ID2D1Factory* factory;
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* target;

void initialize(HWND hwnd)
{
    CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);

    D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &factory);
    factory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
        D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED)),
        D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hwnd, D2D1::SizeU(rc.right, rc.bottom)),
        &target);
}

void on_render()
{
    target->BeginDraw();
    target->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White));

    ID2D1Bitmap* pBitmap = NULL;
    if (SUCCEEDED(LoadBitmapFromFile(L"filename.png", target, &pBitmap)))
    {
        D2D1_SIZE_F size = pBitmap->GetSize();
        target->DrawBitmap(pBitmap, D2D1::RectF(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
        safe_release(pBitmap);
    }

    target->EndDraw();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for noticing that argument problem in CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(). I would have never found it.

But I found different thing. When I change CLSID_WICImagingFactory1 to CLSID_WICImagingFactory, CoCreateInstance() returns REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG.

Comment: I see. There is more information here about `CLSID_WICImagingFactory` [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16699299/4603670). I am in VS2015 on Windows 10, and both `CLSID_WICImagingFactory1` and `CLSID_WICImagingFactory2` work fine.